# Image is not displaying using PHP PDO and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on PHP PDO. I want to insert and display image in MYSQL database.

My table data -

```
itemImage longblob ;
```

I tried this PHP PDO code -

```
 $itemImage = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])); 

    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO items (itemImage) VALUES (:itemImage)') ;
$stmt->execute(array(

    ':itemImage' => $itemImage

));
```

HTML form -

```
 <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <p><label>Item Image </label><br />
<input class="input-group" type="file" name="image" value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['image'];}?>' id="image" style="width:100%;" ></p>


        <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>

    </form>
```

It inserts the blob image .

I am displaying image using the code below .

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($itemImage ).'" height="300" width="300" style="width:100%" class="img-thumnail" />
```

If I upload the image using my HTML form, the image does not display.

if I upload the image using MySQL PHPMyAdmin(Insert), image displays proper

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Why are you using addslashes()?

Comment: Yes, it solved. I removed addslashes(). Thank you. I was confused about this. Now, it's working properly.

Comment: Look at the image path sometimes "path\image.jpg" sometimes "path/images.jpg" ..

Comment: One side comment is that storing images in a database is not ideal, A better approach would be to store them somewhere on your server or on a cloud storage like AWS S3 and add just the file name that you can build the url from in the database.